# Why can't I access variable in my dictionary of JSON object?

Tags: json, swift, string, dictionary

I am going into my JSON object layer by layer to get to a variable that I need.  I've successfully accessed variables in prior parts of my project, but using the exact same methods it won't let me access this particular variable.

I have currently gone about 4 layers deep and successfully grabbed the following data that is equal to the variable "defaultsolo":

`["placetop10": 2512, "minutesplayed": 4249, "lastmodified": 1556152357, "playersoutlived": 28024, "matchesplayed": 5552, "score": 140716, "kills": 39521, "placetop1": 1829, "placetop25": 3050]`

The following code below is my attempt to access the variable "minutesplayed".  defaultsolo is of type [String: Any] and minutesplayed says it's of type String.  My issue is that it keeps saying that defaultSolo["minutesplayed"] is equal to "nil", but there is indeed a value there as seen above.  Because of that, it's never entering the logic below.

```
if let soloPCResult = defaultSolo["minutesplayed"] as? String {
   //perform logic here with saved variable
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple JSON rules:

1. Everything in double quotes is `String`, even `"123"` and `"false"`
2. Numeric values with fractional digits are `Double`, anything else is `Int`

According to the rules – no double quotes and no fractional digits – it's

```
if let soloPCResult = defaultSolo["minutesplayed"] as? Int {
   //perform logic here with saved variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a Int type

Do you try get this field as Int?

```
if let soloPCResult = defaultSolo["minutesplayed"] as? Int {
```

Answer (score 0):

`minutesplayed` is not a string. Try:

```
if let soloPCResult = defaultSolo["minutesplayed"] as? Int {
   //perform logic here with saved variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `minutesplayed` looks like to be an `Int`, you should do like

```swift
if let soloPCResult = defaultSolo["minutesplayed"] as? Int {
   //perform logic here with saved variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because "minutesplayed" is an `Int` and not a `String`